# Cmocka: printing context on test failure

Tags: c, unit-testing, cmocka

I am using CMocka to write some unit tests. Some of my tests loop though a list of cases which are stored in a struct to avoid repetition:

```
typedef struct {
  char* test_arg;
  int expected;
} TestCase;

const static TestCase cases[] = {
    {"1", 1}, {"2", 1},
    {0}
};

void test_the_cases(void **state)
{
    for (const TestCase* case = cases; case->test_arg != NULL; case++)
    {
        int got_result = atoi(case->test_arg);

        // Check the result matches
        // If this fails, this line is where the assertion is
        assert_int_equal(c->expected, got_result);
    }
}
```

This does work:

```
[==========] tests: Running 1 test(s).
[ RUN      ] test_the_cases
[  ERROR   ] --- 0x1 != 0x2
[   LINE   ] --- <file>.c:64: error: Failure!
[  FAILED  ] test_the_cases
[==========] tests: 1 test(s) run.
[  PASSED  ] 0 test(s).
[  FAILED  ] tests: 1 test(s), listed below:
[  FAILED  ] test_the_cases

 1 FAILED TEST(S)
```

However, the assertion is simply at line 64 (`assert_int_equal(...)`), and in this case, the failed case is clear. But, it isn't always - perhaps the failure is a number that doesn't appear directly in the case, or is shared between cases, meaning you can't tell from the `ERROR` and `LINE` which `TestCase` failed. I don't really want to `printf()` every case, or there'll be thousands of lines of spam in the tests, but I also don't want to have to re-run tests with debugging levels raised to see what failed.

With Boost Test, I could use a message or context ([docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/test_output/contexts.html)) to do this and print a handy message on failure (including nice things like RAII scope, but it's C++, so that's why). In Cmocka, I have the `state` parameter to store messages in if I need, however, I can't see how I can hook into an assertion *failure* to print that message to the user.

It occurs that if you know if tests failed during teardown, you could implement a stack of strings with `state`, push and pop during execution and print them if failure occured, but as it is, I can't see that the teardown callback has any idea of the test pass/fail status.

Is this possible in CMocka?